# Sharing tests between developers using Xcode, what's going on?

Tags: xcode, testing

In Xcode 6.2 I created a test target called CommonTests:

[image]

and wrote some tests in it that are all passing on my machine:

[image]

I marked the scheme as shared so other developers could easily run them:

[image]

Another developer tried to run them and got an error that I don't understand yet, but in the investigation, we discovered his Xcode is seeing the test target quite differently than mine:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas what's going on? Anything we can delete for Xcode to refresh the known tests from the code and shared scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what I was seeing, like the list of tests, is gathered by Xcode after running the tests and because the tests were crashing, it was never gathered. It was an irrelevant side effect to the actual problem.

The actual problem is that the tests were targeting 10.10 and the other developers were running 10.9.